# Data inserted on MongoDB only saves ID using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I have this Express, NodeJS, MongoDB(mLab) as my project

I have inserted three strings on Postman to `http://localhost:3000/api/comment` and it is successfully inserted but when I checked on my Database on mLab.com it only contains an ID

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b7d0f70f097a71eccb9b360"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have a model like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    comment: String,
    date: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

and I have my server.js like this

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var api = require("./app/routes/api")(app, express);

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*',(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true },(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
});



app.listen(config.port, (err) =>{ 
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Listening on port:'+ config.port);
    }
});
```

and my api.js which where my POST method at is like this

```
var User = require('../models/user');


module.exports = function(app,express){

    var api = express.Router();

    api.post('/comment', function(req,res){
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            comment: req.body.comment,
            date: req.body.date
        });

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            res.json({ message: "User has commented"});
        });
    });

    return api;
}
```

any ideas why it only contains ID not those three strings I inserted?

Comment: Did you try testing it with Postman? What data are you sending in req body?

Comment: I did. Postman returned a success to me but no item in database. I sent 3 strings

Answer (score 1):

Am thinking your database connection should come after initialising the express app, then your middlewares and routing can follow.
**Steps**

**1.**
`var app = express();`

**2.**

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true },(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
})
```

**3.** Middlewares

**4.** Routing

I think the problem has to do with how Nodejs is parsing the lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Am thinking your database connection should come after initialising the express app, then your middlewares and routing can follow.

**Steps**

**1.** `var app = express();`

**2.** `mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true },(err)=>{`
    `if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
});`

**3.** Middlewares

**4.** Routing

I think the problem has to do with how Nodejs is parsing the lines of code.